# Using FCM in Cordova

Tags: android, json, cordova, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using FCM in a Cordova project. I created a project in FCM web console and generated the `google-services.json` file with my project's package name `com.mycompany.myapp`. I had to put this file in two places to succeed compilation: the android project root folder and the 'CordovaLib' sub-folder. The problem is that each of these two copies should specify a different package name: the copy of the project root folder should specify `com.mycompany.myapp` and the copy in `CordovaLib` should specify `com.apache.cordova`. Otherwise, the project will not compile.

When I modify the package name in the file `google-services.json` manually, the compilation succeeds, but no notification are delivered.

My question is: how can I generate a `google-services.json` file that works with Cordova? What package name should I specify in FCM console (`com.mycompany.myapp` or `com.mycompany.myapp`)? Can I generate a file that works for many packages?

[EDIT]

If you need to know, the Cordova project is generated from a Sencha ExtJS6 application, and I use "cordova-plugin-fcm". In `platforms\android` folder, there is a folder called `CordovaLib` that contains `build.gradle` and `src`. The project will not compile if I don't copy `google-services.json` to this location. the classes in this `src` folder have the package name `com.apache.cordova`.

Comment: what plugin are you using? you shouldn't need to create a google-services.json for the `com.apache.cordova`, it's a library project

Comment: The README of the of the cordova-plugin-fcm indicates that you should only need to add the google-services.json file to the root of your project. Is that not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the comments on the question suggested, the solution was to put `google-services.json` in the root of the project only. I will explain why I had this problem, so that others may not commit the same error.

When you create your project and application in Firebase Console, you get a window with the following instructions:

> Add Firebase to your Android app
>
> The Google services plugin for Gradle loads the google-services.json file you just downloaded. Modify your build.gradle files to use the plugin.
>
> 1 - Project-level build.gradle (<project\>/build.gradle):
>
> buildscript {
>
> dependencies {
>
> ```
> // Add this line
>
> classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
> ```
>
> }
>
> }
>
> 2 - App-level build.gradle (<project>/<app-module>/build.gradle):
>
> ...
>
> // Add to the bottom of the file
>
> apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

So, I added the `apply plugin ...` line in the `build.gradle` file in the sub-folder `CordovaLib` (which is wrong, it should go in the same `build.gradle` file in the project root folder), and it would not compile unles I add `google-services.json` in that folder. So, the source of the error was following the above instructions without thinking.

Conclusion: In Android applications generated by Cordova, put both modifications in the `build.gradle` file at the root of the project, and put `google-services.json` in the root only.